# Confused about multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I just read some where that C# class can't inherit from multiple class, at the same time I also read that each C# class is inherited from a base class "Object Class".

Now I am confused if I make another class make it to inherit some class, then it is inheriting from the class and the base class, ie two class.

Isn't it breaking the law?

Comment: Object class is parent of all. But it has too many grand children.

Comment: Object --> String (Inherits from Object) --> MyClass : String (Inherits from String).... Each One of these only inherits from its parent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each class inherits from one other class. If you make your own class extend one of your other classes, then it will not directly inherit from `Object` but rather from your superclass. The superclass in its turn will inherit from `Object`.

Your subclass will have all the methods from `Object` available trough the superclass.

This will illustrate it:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine (new Super().GetType().BaseType);
    Console.WriteLine (new Sub().GetType().BaseType);
}

class Super { }
class Sub : Super { }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Pedantic note: The object class inherits from zero classes.

Answer (score 10):

**This is possible in C#:**

[image]

(One base class per derived class, aka "single [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)")

**This is not possible in C#:**

[image]

([Multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance), use [interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computing%29) instead in C#)

Answer (score 7):

> I just read some where that C# class can't inherit from multiple class, at the same time I also read that each C# class is inherited from a base class "Object. Now I am confused.

Every C# class except object inherits **directly** from **exactly one** other class.  Object inherits from no class.

A C# class can inherit *indirectly* from any (non-negative!) number of classes.

```
class Animal : Object {}
class Giraffe : Animal {}
```

Are our rules met? Yes. Object inherits from no class. Animal inherits directly from Object and indirectly from no class. Giraffe inherits directly from Animal and indirectly from Object.

This eliminates the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Every class, except Object itself, will implictly extend Object if it does not extend another class. Thus all classes implictly always eventually extend from Object.

The only common programming language supporting multiple inheritance is C++, it's explictly not allowed in most languages for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

One class can inherit from one other class directly and implement multiple interfaces.
You can chain inheritance, eg class a inherits from class b while class c inherits from class a.

```
interface i {}
class a {}
class b : a {}   // OK
class c : i,b {} // OK
class d : a,b {} // Not OK
```

Answer (score 0):

*Multiple inheritance* means that a class' inheritance tree can be branched as desired (i.e. it can inherit from more than one base classes at the same time). That's (thank god) not possible in C#.

But as long as the inheritance tree has always only one 'upper leg', it can be as deep as required (i.e. there is something like an inheritance 'chain', where one class inherits from the other).

Answer (score 0):

It does not break the rule.

Every class in C# will inherit from exactly one class. That class either is any class the author of that class wants to extend, or, if none specified, it will extend the `Object` class.

```
public class MyClass {} // extends from default Object class
```

would be exactly the same as

```
public class MyClass : object {}
```

Or, when the author wants to extend a specified class:

```
public class MyClass : AnyBaseClass {}
```